# How do I extract a single column from another database?

Tags: php

Why this condition passes even if I change the `$_GET` variable?

I've this code

```
elseif(isset($_GET['results']) && $_GET['results'] == 'reorder' && 
isset($_GET['sort_column']) && $_GET['sort_column'] != '' && isset($_GET['sort_order']) 
&& $_GET['sort_order'] != '' && $_GET['sort_order'] == 'asc' 
|| $_GET['sort_order'] == 'desc') { /*rest goes here*/ } else {redirect}
```

Link returns like this

```
http://localhost/system/results.php?script_id=2&results=reorder&sort_column=supplier_address&sort_order=desc
```

But when I change this `sort_column=supplier_address` to say for example  `sorcodsalumn=supplier_address` it doesn't redirect, instead goes ahead, any idea why? But if I simply remove few letters and dont replace with something else it does redirect...

How come if am using this `isset($_GET['sort_column']` and am modifying `sort_column` to something else still passes this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic PHP [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)... `&&` evaluates before `||`, so your entire statement boils down to:

```
(x && y && z && ....) || ($_GET['sort_order'] == 'desc')
```

You need to simplify that if(), add some `()` to enforce your own evaluation order, and then things should start working a bit better.

Comment: Oh that was so dumb of me, I forgot precedence stuff, thank you very much +1

Answer (score 1):

your AND's and OR's need to be bracketed properly.

```
else if (isset($_GET['results']) && 
         $_GET['results'] == 'reorder' && 
         isset($_GET['sort_column']) &&
         $_GET['sort_column'] != '' &&
         isset($_GET['sort_order']) && 
         $_GET['sort_order'] != '' &&
         ($_GET['sort_order'] == 'asc' || $_GET['sort_order'] == 'desc')) 
 { 
     /*rest goes here*/ 
 } else {
     redirect
 }
```

More specifically your last || needs its own brackets, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a bracket around your || (OR) statement like this:

```
elseif(isset($_GET['results']) && $_GET['results'] == 'reorder' && 
isset($_GET['sort_column']) && $_GET['sort_column'] != '' && isset($_GET['sort_order']) 
&& $_GET['sort_order'] != '' && ($_GET['sort_order'] == 'asc' 
|| $_GET['sort_order'] == 'desc')) { /*rest goes here*/ } else {redirect}
```

Otherwise your statement will return true anytime sort_order is set to 'desc'.